# UITabelView Custom Cell Misplace Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm adding a custom cell and I have placed it to be near to each other but unfortunately there is a misplacing as in the picture below. Please where would be my issue?

I have adjusted the constraints.

[image]

Normally my storyboard design is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using size classes? if so then you have to add/remove your preferences in the relevant size class

Comment: No, I'm not adding size classes.

Comment: please, check constraints for top,bottom, left, right, width and height. Also if possible go with 2 labels and then add others one by one for debugging the issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: After adding each label and add its constraints one by one it started working great. Thanks.